# Hashicorp's Nomad template explanation

Tags: hcl, hashicorp, nomad

With Hashicorp Nomad one can define a template through which a file can be created on a Docker containers storage - provided that `driver="docker". The template looks like the following:

```
template {
        data = <<EOF
{{ source from parameter store }}
EOF
        destination   = "secrets/certificate.pem"
      }
```

How is Nomad able to do such a thing confuses me. I want to achieve the same thing using Terraform while creating an ECS container definition and the only option I have is to create an EFS manually where I should load manually the secrets from the parameter store and then bind that volume via container definitions.

How does Nomad achieve that?

Comment: `can define a template through which a file can be created on a Docker` I do not understand the sentence. `How is Nomad able to do such a thing confuses me` Which part is confusing? `source from parameter store` is the "parameter store" something specific?

Comment: The parameter store is the AWS parameter store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nomad [template block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/job-specification/template) actually works somewhat similarly to the EFS solution you described.

Here's how Nomad does it:

1. When Nomad schedules an allocation, it creates [several directories](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template) on the host
2. The Nomad agent on the host runs [consul-template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template) to render any templates within the task directories on the host.
3. When Nomad starts a Docker container, it mounts the task directories inside the container, e.g. `/data/nomad/alloc/<alloc-uuid>/alloc` would be at `/alloc` in the container.

If you manage the Docker images you use with ECS, you could achieve similar behavior by [setting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment) the [container entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) to use consul-templates's [`exec` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) to wrap the container process. This would require `consul-template` to be installed at a known path in your container.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could override the container's entrypoint - this was my initial idea - but unfortunately, I cannot. So the combination of using ECS, not being able to override the entrypoint and not using Nomad result in me going with the EFS approach in the end.

Answer (score 0):

> How does Nomad achieve that?

- The template content `{{ source from parameter store }}` is sent from Nomad server to Nomad client after choosing it for scheduling.
- Then Nomad client process,

  - creates task directories `local` `secrets` etc.,
  - runs a go-template engine that generates the file content from template
  - the file content is written to proper location at `secrets/certificate.pem`
  - and then an allocation is executed with proper environment